# On my webpage the menu doesn't work on phones. It collapses fine but doesn't do anything when I click it

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

On my webpage the menu doesn't work on phones.  It collapses fine but doesn't do anything when I click it.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hoa_label" onclick="newPage('m_page1','page1')">Wedding Event</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active" id="m_page1"><a onclick="newPage('m_page1','page1')">Home</a></li>
                <li id="m_page2"><a onclick="newPage('m_page2','page2')">Photos</a></li>
                <li id="m_page3"><a onclick="newPage('m_page3','page3')">RSVP</a></li>
                <li id="m_page4"><a onclick="newPage('m_page4','page4')">Gift Registry</a></li>
                <li id="m_page5"><a onclick="newPage('m_page5','page5')">Hotel Information</a></li>
                <li id="m_page6"><a onclick="newPage('m_page6','page6')">Wedding Contacts</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Event Information<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="https://www.chateauelan.com/" target="_blank">Venue</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank">Live Streaming</a></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the section that loads the java.  It won't let me post any more code into this post.  It's forcing me to 'add' details, so hopefully this is enough.  It's just the standard * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com) with absolutely no changes. The only custom java script is a little toggle to check a cookie to turn on and off the help prompts.

```
    <!--Javascript Load Files-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <!--QTip Start-->
    <script>
        $(function ()
        {
            $(document).tooltip(
            {
                track: true
            });
        } );
    </script>
    <!--QTip End-->
    <script src="js/singleAppFunc.js"></script>
```

Comment: On which phone platform does the problem reproduce?  [tag:ios]? [tag:android]?

Comment: Would you paste your JS please?

Comment: I'm trying to use in on and Iphone IOS version 13.3.1

Comment: I'm using the standard bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js

Comment: The webpage is 'http://www.veniceoptometry.com/OpeyemiAde/' if you want to look at it